# Not able to Parse HTML data attribute value as Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the JS and HTML Code as below

```js
var a=$("li").data("item");
console.log($("li").data("item").type);
```

```html
  <li  data-item="{&quot;contentId&quot; : 5,&quot;type&quot; : &quot;PROGRAM&quot;, section_type:  &quot;PROGRAM_SECTION&quot;, &quot;active&quot;:&quot;false&quot;  }">data</li>
```

Trying to get the JS Object's `type` property value in the data-item attribute using the code

```
var a=$("li").data("item");
console.log($("li").data("item").type);
```

But I got `var a=$("li").data("item");` as string, even JSON.parse(a) also not working see the screenshot [image]and codepen http://codepen.io/shmdhussain/pen/VvXKLr

Please help me in parse the data. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found a few things wrong:

1: It should be

```
$("li").data("sna-item");
```

Also, you have an error in your `data-sna-item` (It's not valid json). There are no quotes around `section_type`

Here's an updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaewrd

Comment: Thanks FrankerZ for spotting the mistake.

Comment: For better readability I'd write `<li data-sna-item='{"contentId": 5, "type": "PROGRAM", "section_type": "PROGRAM_SECTION", "active": false}'>data</li>` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVEgpv

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few issues... try using the below HTML and JS instead.

HTML

```
<li data-item="{&quot;contentId&quot; : 5,
&quot;type&quot; : &quot;PROGRAM&quot;,
&quot;section_type&quot;:  &quot;PROGRAM_SECTION&quot;, 
&quot;active&quot; :&quot;false&quot;} ">data</li>
```

JS

```
var item = $("li").data("item");
var json = JSON.parse(item);    
$("li").text(json.type);
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your data is using `&quot;` when it should be using " so you need to replace `&quot;` with "

use this

```
JSON.parse($("li").data("item").replace(/&quot;/g,'"')).type;
```

assuming `$("li").data("item")` yields the data you wish to parse.